# Добавить и убрать backgroundImage по нажатию

Tags: javascript

```
play.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (playTest.style.backgroundImage === 'url(img/pause.png)' ){
    playTest.style.backgroundImage = '';
  }
  else {
    playTest.style.backgroundImage = 'url(img/pause.png)';
  }
});
```

Изначально у `playTest backgroundImage = play.png`
В первой итерации при нажатии должно не проходить проверку и добавлять `(img/pause.png)`, на следующий клик добавлять пустой `backgroundImage`, тем самым давая работать изначальному, но у меня почему-то не применяется пустой `bgImg`, либо любой другой с рандомными значениями.

Comment: `"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input",`

Comment: Недавно на сайте, так что с тем как правильно вставлять куски кода не разбираюсь.

Comment: Минус ставлю Вам тогда.

Comment: @onelevalde, на сайте используется довольно удобный Markdown, вот подробное описание по использованию - [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 1):

Я бы советовал завязать смену картинки на CSS, а через JS менять класс - так удобнее, я считаю.

```js
let play = document.getElementById('play');
play.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  if(e.target.classList.contains('-play')) {
    e.target.classList.remove('-play');
    e.target.classList.add('-pause');
  } else {
    e.target.classList.remove('-pause');
    e.target.classList.add('-play');
  }
  return false;
});
```

```css
#play {
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: contain;
}

#play.-play {
  background-image: url('//i.imgur.com/0K47nDu.png');
}

#play.-pause {
  background-image: url('//i.imgur.com/KVOlqKD.png');
}
```

```html
<div class="music-box-2">
  <a href="#" id="play" class="musicIcon -play"></a>
</div>
```